# Overly complicated selector, needs to be made simple

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have wrote a script and it function how I want it too but the selector is awful, has anyone got a better suggestion than what Ive done selector wise?

The script I wrote working is here, but is not eloquent at all!
http://jsfiddle.net/xxsqye3q/

Just incase the fiddle goes missing at some point:

```
$('body').on('click','.js_spec', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.file-spec-container').slideUp(200);
    $(this)
    .parent()
    .first()
    .next()
    .children()
    .closest('.file-spec-container:hidden')
    .slideDown(200);
})
```

Comment: what do you want to get?

Comment: Have you considered a specific class name for the target elements?

Comment: Isn't that enough? : http://jsfiddle.net/xxsqye3q/1/

Comment: The `.first()` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: side note:  `<img src="http://placehold.it/274x149"/><br />` close the brackets properly , it hurts my eyes

Comment: @Holybreath: `<img ...>` and `<br>` are perfectly proper, in HTML. The extra `/` at the end is nothing but bloat, there's exactly zero reason for adding it. This isn't XHTML.

Comment: If we keep this up , soon , divs will not be closed , and etc. heh. It's perfectly legit, I know. Depends on a person. peace.

Comment: @Holybreath: No, there's no slippery slope here, it's always been this way. `img` and `br` are void elements, `div` isn't. That's why they can't have closing tags and don't need a solidus in their standalone tag. And they never have. The solidus-in-standalone-tag is just an XHTML thing, added years after HTML was created, because XHTML is XML. The slippery slope is *here*: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target `.file-spec-container` element is a descendant of the next sibling of current element's parent

```
$('body').on('click', '.js_spec', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $(this)
        .parent()
        .next()
        .find('.file-spec-container:hidden')
        .slideDown(200);
    $('.file-spec-container').not($target).slideUp(200);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c55ecpvk/)

Answer (score 0):

Already this is a better step using `find`:

```
$('body').on('click','.js_spec', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.file-spec-container').slideUp(200);
    $(this)
        .parent().find('.file-spec-container:hidden')
        .slideDown(200);
})
```

EDIT:

Since some comments have appeared making me second-guess my original answer perhaps this makes it even simpler?

```
$('body').on('click', '.js_spec', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.file-spec-container').slideToggle(200);
})
```

Comment: @RobSchmuecker it is not working.. the `file-spec-container` element is hidden by `$('.file-spec-container')`... so the `slideDown()` is not doing anything